# x86 Instruction Encoding C++ Pointer as Address

Tags: pointers, encoding, x86

I'm trying to encode x86 instructions to take an address specified by a C++ pointer.  For example, I have a 32 bit number that I would like to move to the eax register.  In assembly, this is easy.

```
mov eax, number
```

I would like to encode in binary the x86 instruction to do this using a C++ pointer to the number.  The opcode for mov (memory to register 32 bit) is 0x8B.  I am not sure what to use for the Mod-Reg-R/M byte and the displacement.  Is there a way to encode the address from the pointer directly?  Or do I have to do some displacement math?  Also, I don't really understand  how displacement works.

The instructions will be stored and called in dynamically allocated memory.  This is for a dynamic recompiler for an emulator.  I have tried all sorts of combinations with Mod-Reg-R/M and the pointer, with no luck.  I also haven't been able to find anything online explaining how this works.

Comment: In 32bit mode, `mov eax, [dword]` is `8B 05 dword`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Not quite.  The address that gets encoded in that case is very different than the C++ pointer.  For example, if I do it in a __asm block, the instruction is 0x8BAD6CFFFFFF and the C++ pointer is 0x0014FDF0.  I don't understand where the x86 address comes from

Comment: I don't see how that code makes sense, it seems to be encoding `mov ebp, [ebp - 148]`

Comment: I'm not sure.  That's what it compiles to when using a C++ variable inside an __asm block.  Another example, mov eax, var is 0x8B8560FFFFFF.  Pointer is 0x002CFB98.  I have found absolutely no information about converting a C++ pointer to an assembly address.  Is it even possible?

Comment: Hold on, aren't you actually just loading the variable there? A ModR/M of 85 is `eax, [ebp + sdword]` so that makes sense for loading a local variable into `eax`. Btw, a pointer is almost always just the raw address (except member pointers).

Comment: I got it now.  I just have to use 2 instructions.  First one moves the pointer into a register as an immediate value.  Second moves it again to dereference it.  Is there a way I can do that using 1 instruction?  I'm new to x86 assembly.

Comment: You can't double-dereference in one x86 instruction, so if the pointer has to come from memory it will take (at least) two instructions.

Comment: But it would only need 1 dereference.  I'm not reading the pointer's value from memory.  I'm encoding it directly into the instruction.  Can I dereference an immediate value in 1 instruction?  This is what I'm doing

//Move pointer into eax as an immediate value
mov eax, 12345678h
//Dereference eax
mov eax, dword ptr[eax]

Can I do this in 1 instruction?  I'm sorry, that formatted horribly since it's not allowing newlines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46044/discussion-between-harold-and-janz-dott)